# Google App Engine Datastore multi-valued properties matches only when having > 1 values

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, multivalue

I have a data table as follows.

[image: data table]

When I execute the GQL from the Admin Console:

```
SELECT * FROM DbFeed WHERE broadcasterAccountNames='gmnexuss@gmail.com'
```

The result I got is only 1 row, which is the one with id=10001. What's wrong with it? Why didn't it return me the one with id=1002 too?

Comment: Are the 2 records in different namespaces?

Comment: maybe the first record was not indexed (index added later ?)

Comment: @koma, if i'm not wrong, index of single property is always added automatically? I don't have any manually/automatically generated index in my app. Is it even possible to have an index that only apply to some (not all) rows?

Comment: @Bert How do I check the namespace? There should not be any other namespaces, since I have never added any namespaces.

Comment: If you have namespace there is an option (under options) to choose namespace where querying in console. However, if you never added namespace, then I don't suspect it is a namespacing issue.

Comment: what happens if you run a query in code, does it still only return 1 record?

Comment: @yuku No, the index is built at write time AFAIK. The index is added without config but previously written records not indexed. Re-write the record and try again.

Comment: @Bert using namespace, this looks different in the console cfr screenshot

Comment: @yuku is this resolved?